# cellClick Event not triggering Angular 4 Kendo UI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I can't trigger this event, I have used code samples from telerik but it just won't work.

```
 <kendo-grid
                        [data]="serviceProductPricingData | async"
                        [height]="533"
                        [pageSize]="gridState.take" [skip]="gridState.skip"  
                        [sort]="gridState.sort"
                        (cellClick)="cellClickHandler($event)"
                        (cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)">
```

Comment: I don't remeber, is kendo free to use? Anyway can you provide a stackblitzs so we can work on that?

Comment: This feature is supported in versions 1.4.0 and above. Thank you @JacopoSciampi for your time.